# IBM MobileFirst - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: oracle, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio, mobilefirst-server

I'm developing hybrid application using IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio (v6.3 - former IBM Worklight).

Since there is a requirement to call Oracle stored PL/SQL procedures which contain OUT params I used a solution offered here [How to get OUT parameter when invoking a stored procedure?](http://goo.gl/qyTqZ3) - calling stored procedure in java and calling java class from adapter procedure.

I added StoredProcedure.java src file to server/java folder inside my project. I also added commons-dbutils-1.6.jar and ojdbc6.jar to server/lib folder. StoredProcedure class got built on save and deployed on MobileFirst Development server. I also defined needed datasource in server.xml but when I try to test the adapter procedure I implemented (R-click on adapter Run as -> Deploy MobileFirstAdapter, R-Click on adapter Run as -> Invoke MobileFirst Procedure) I get this error message:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project MxP]StoredProcedure/pretragaVozilaFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project MxP]
invocation of javascript function 'pretragaVozila' has failed: ResultSetHandler
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project MxP]java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ResultSetHandlerjava.lang.RuntimeException:
    invocation of javascript function 'pretragaVozila' has failed: ResultSetHandler
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:52)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:54)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:593)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:539)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:58)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$3.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:433)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:430)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:139)
    at com.worklight.server.dev.InvokeProcedureHandler.handle(InvokeProcedureHandler.java:85)
    at com.worklight.server.dev.DevRootServlet.service(DevRootServlet.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:767)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:469)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:151)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1056)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4553)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:301)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:266)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:776)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ResultSetHandler
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1860)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.discoverAccessibleMethods(JavaMembers.java:315)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.discoverAccessibleMethods(JavaMembers.java:302)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.reflect(JavaMembers.java:419)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.<init>(JavaMembers.java:43)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.lookupClass(JavaMembers.java:807)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.initMembers(NativeJavaClass.java:49)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject.<init>(NativeJavaObject.java:44)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.<init>(NativeJavaClass.java:43)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaClass.<init>(NativeJavaClass.java:39)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.WrapFactory.wrapJavaClass(WrapFactory.java:134)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.getPkgProperty(NativeJavaPackage.java:133)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaPackage.get(NativeJavaPackage.java:82)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.getProperty(ScriptableObject.java:2184)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1492)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1485)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1239)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:815)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:109)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:107)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:267)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:241)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:211)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:124)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ResultSetHandler
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:265)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:411)
... 59 more
com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
```

What else should I do so that backend service finds commons-dbutils-1.6.jar ?

I'm running Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) on Windows 7 64bit with 64bit Java v1.7.0.72, connecting to Oracle Server 11g.

Comment: Is the Java file actually deployed? You can verify by finding the .war file in the bin folder, open it (you can rename it to .zip) and see if the file exists within.

Comment: Hi, Idan! Yes there are class files and all .jar files inside the project .war in bin folder...

Comment: If I put commons-dbutils src files in server/java and compile them I can get one step further - now I get: FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project MxP]javax.naming.NamingException: CWWKN0008E: An object could not be obtained for name jdbc/OracleDS.java.lang.RuntimeException: invocation of javascript function 'pretragaVozila' has failed: CWWKN0008E: An object could not be obtained for name jdbc/OracleDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping the necessary jars in the server/lib dir hasn't worked for me. I have to copy the required jars (dbutils) and the custom jar created for calling the stored proc in the following dir in the Eclipse workspace relative to the WorklightServerConfig

```
<workspace>/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources
```

which maps to the following variable in the server.xml

```
${shared.resource.dir}
```

then define the oracle lib, I have the ojdbc6.jar in a sub-directory named oracle

```
<library id="ORACLE_LIB">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/oracle" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>

<connectionManager id="OraclePool" maxPoolSize="40" minPoolSize="10"/>

<dataSource id="mobileDatasource" jndiName="jdbc/mobile__datasource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="ORACLE_LIB"/>
    <properties.oracle URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@..." password="..." user="..."/>
</dataSource>
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks! I did the oracle part the same way you did but I stayed with java src files under server/java folder which then compile and make their way into .war file. I find it strange that there does not exist a standard way of including jar dependencies into backend...